# Create variable that contains a string and std::endl, that can be used in output streams to std::cout

Tags: c++, c++17, cout, stringstream, ostringstream

Using `c++17`

I have a header file `colors.hpp` to help me with colored output to stdout:

```
#pragma once
#include <string>

namespace Color
{
    static const std::string yellow = "\u001b[33m";
    static const std::string green = "\u001b[32m";
    static const std::string red = "\u001b[31m";
    static const std::string end = "\u001b[0m";
}
```

I often use it like this:

```
std::cout << Color::green << "some green text " << Color::end << std::endl;
```

I almost always put `std::endl` immediately after `Color::end`. I'd like to be able to achieve the same result (newline + buffer flush), but use only one variable - something like `Color::endl`.

I've only been able to come up with solutions that are `string`, which as far as I understand, will include the `\n` character but will not also force the flush to stdout.

```
static const std::string endl = std::ostringstream(static_cast<std::ostringstream &&>(std::ostringstream() << Color::end << std::endl)).str();
```

If I remove the `.str()` from the code above, then I can't do:
`std::cout << Color::endl;` because of

```
error: invalid operands to binary expression ('basic_ostream<char>' and 'const std::__1::basic_ostringstream<char>')
```

Comment: You might create a *"io-manipulator"*.

Comment: What about some macro stuff? http://ix.io/3yhN

Comment: You can reset the color and end the line automatically with this, if you're interested: https://godbolt.org/z/cMP9rjzvf

Comment: @GhasemRamezani I also sometimes use a few different colors per line,  so the macros arent ideal for that case. I'm also trying to avoid macros because I'm trying to move away from the C99 style of writing C++

Comment: @m88 thank you for providing that, it is a useful and instructive example!

Answer (score 10, accepted):

`std::endl` is a function (actually function template), not an object.  That means, if you want to replicate it, you need a function as well.

If you add this to `Color`:

```
template< class CharT, class Traits >
std::basic_ostream<CharT, Traits>& endl( std::basic_ostream<CharT, Traits>& os )
{ 
    return os << end << std::endl;
}
```

Then, when you use this:

```
std::cout << Color::green << "some green text " << Color::endl;
```

The `Color::endl()` function will get called, and then it can insert `Color::end` into the stream, and then `std::endl` to get the newline and flush behavior you want, as seen in this [live example](http://coliru.stacked-crooked.com/a/1cd41fad3a2acbb2).